# How to open ws. files in datasets?

Tags: dataset

I have to use the datasets on http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/support/datasets/.
And I found every data set on this website has a ws. file. I try to download software which can open it and I can get the data. But I do not find a free one. It is very disappointed.
Could you recommend one for me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about looking for a software recommendation for opening a file type.

Comment: Oh, Where should I be better to put this question?

Comment: @gung Although this is a really marginal topic, I'm stuck on where to send the question. It's not about software development.  One could make a case that it's of general interest, at least insofar as anyone would be interested in obtaining data in this format: that's not a platform-specific question.

Comment: @whuber, I don't know where it should go, but I do think it's off-topic for CV. It also may not matter much; the OP's question seems to have been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are opened with MLwiN which can be downloaded free from the CMM website http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/software/mlwin/ if you are a UK academic after filling out a registration form if I remember correctly. There is a 30-day demo if you are not a UK academic.

Comment: Thanks. I install it. But when I try to open a .ws, it cannot open it.

Comment: I downloaded the first dataset (asian.zip), extracted to a folder and then double clicked on the .ws file and it opened up fine. Is there a particular dataset you cannot open or is it all of them?

Comment: Yes, Height growth data (zip, 0.1 mb) Height measurements on 26 boys on 9 occasions.

Comment: ,I try Asian also. It is ok.

Comment: The ASC and DAT files are plain text. ASC file tells you which columns match which variables so you could easily load DAT file into Excel. I agree that particular .ws file does not load.